# PHP switch statement - calculating chinese zodiac year

Tags: php, switch-statement

Hi i'm trying to calculate to find out which year has which zodiac by using a remainder value but I do not understand the equation. 
in  this equation: ($year - 4) % 12,
why do you subtract 4 and then get a remainder of it by dividing it into 12 in order to calculate the zodiac year?
I understand that if you do (1996 - 4) % 12 = 166.0 so the remainder is 0 so it is a 'RAT' year. but **where is the equation from and what is the meaning of it?**

```
$year = 1996;
        switch (($year - 4) % 12) 
        {
            case  0: $zodiac = 'Rat';       break;
            case  1: $zodiac = 'Ox';        break;
            case  2: $zodiac = 'Tiger';     break;
            case  3: $zodiac = 'Rabbit';    break;
            case  4: $zodiac = 'Dragon';    break;
            case  5: $zodiac = 'Snake';     break;
            case  6: $zodiac = 'Horse';     break;
            case  7: $zodiac = 'Goat';      break;
            case  8: $zodiac = 'Monkey';    break;
            case  9: $zodiac = 'Rooster';   break;
            case 10: $zodiac = 'Dog';       break;
            case 11: $zodiac = 'Pig';       break;
        }
        echo "{$year} is the year of the {$zodiac}.<br />";
```

Comment: I don't think this a php question..

Comment: @wateriswet actually after reading the question better, you might be right xP, but I can't be completely sure... he is asking more a mathematical question than a coding one.

Comment: @Webeng, lol, thanks for making me delete my long-ass retort.

Comment: @wateriswet hahah you were writing a page on why i was wrong? hahah maybe I'm a genius troller that deserves an oscar for my indirect trolling methods? xP

Comment: @wateriswet truth is I don't mind admitting when I'm wrong. If I did mind, I wouldn't learn as much as I could have.

Comment: @Webeng, yea man you trolled me good, it had citations of the Terms of Service and everything.

Comment: 100% divided by 12 is 8.3% per sign. I think the remainder is used to indicate the fraction of 100 left over. The remainder of 1997 - 4 / 12 is .083 so this really does show the total number of individual 8.3%s that keep adding up over the years until you loop back to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cycle counted since thousands years ago so it's simply the way found to convert to/from the Common Era. But don't worry, there is no leap or exception so the equation always works. For more details you can refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagenary_cycle

Both 12-year cycle and 60-year cycle are for easy year count since a long time ago.

Answer (score 0):

heavily optimized version of the code if anyone else came here looking for how to do this, not why it was done:

```
$zodiacs = ['Monkey', 'Rooster', 'Dog', 'Pig', 'Rat', 'Ox', 'Tiger', 'Rabbit', 'Dragon', 'Snake', 'Horse', 'Goat'];
$zodiac = $zodiacs[$year % 12];
```